# DB Roundtrips of entity updating in the repository pattern

Tags: object-oriented

I'm trying to wrap my head around OOP when building simple CRUD systems, using the [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to handle object retrieval/saving to persistent storage.

I've already designed and implemented a system that doesn't use OOP, just straight up get, insert, update and delete functions that contain SQL queries.

#### Non-OOP way

For example, for updating a customer I would call this function:

```js
// PUT customer
function updateCustomer(idCustomer, data) {
  db("customer").update(data).where("idCustomer", idCustomer);
}
```

#### OOP way

Now, to implement this in OOP using the [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) I would do something like:

```js
// PUT customer
customer = customerRepo.getById(idCustomer);
customer.setData(data);
customerRepo.update(customer);
```

#### OOP way seems to require an extra DB roundtrip

This OOP pattern seems to require DB roundtrips since I need to:

- Instantiate a new customer object from the DB using the repo
- Update the data in the object
- Save the object back to the DB using the repo

#### Question

Isn't my current, non-OOP way of doing things more efficient? If yes, are there any common solutions to these roundtrips when following the 2nd OOP method?

Comment: where do you get data from

Comment: As mentioned in the question, a database.

Comment: yeah, so you are missing that step in the first example

Answer (score 1):

This isn't right. You're comparing two different things. A more fair and perfectly equal method for the second example would be:

```
// PUT customer
customer = Customer();
customer.setId(customerId);
customer.setData(data);
customerRepo.update(customer);
```

And in that scenario, you're also only doing one query (the update) but it's still more object-oriented. Your problem is that you're creating a "strawman" argument, suggesting that getting the customer from the database first is somehow intrinsic to object-orientation and the pattern, but that's not true. OOP, Repositories, and whether or not to get the data from the database first have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I got a bit caught up in the details and in the process convinced myself that  I should only instantiate `Customer` objects using the `CustomerRepo`

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides depending on what implementation of the pattern you are using, you can MERGE or "add" the object to the repository after you assign it an ID. if the repository already knows about an entity with the same identity, it can let you know.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides not every ORM framework that supports the pattern will work the same way.  If you're rolling your own repo then how it works will be up to you.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides one thing to think about too is that if you need to ensure the integrity of your data and want ACID compliant updates, you'll need to use something like optimistic locking with an incrementing version number.  And in order to make that work, you'll need to get the data from its persistent storage first to know what it's current version number is. So while not necessary, just because you're getting the data first doesn't mean you're doing something bad.

Comment: Aren't ACID compliance and method of locking handled by the DB? Why do I have to worry about them in this context?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides even an ACID complaint database is happy to persist data on a row that was just updated by another client, completely blowing away the contents of the previous write.  As long as the constraints are satisfied, it's totally possible for one client's write to be negated just after it's committed. ACIDity doesn't mean your application handles this situation, it just means that the DB data structures aren't corrupted.  You still need a mechanism for one client or connection to know that the data was changed out from under it by another.

Comment: That is not a repository pattern. That is just exposing plain SQL as somehow different methods.

Comment: @Euphoric did you read my comments?  Nothing in the repository pattern suggests that "getting" an object via the repository nor creating one via a factory or some other method presupposes a database call.

Comment: What if "data" is not complete description of an entity? Are you suggesting the Customer object keeps track of what properties are "set" and update only those? Also, all definitions of repository I know describe it as "abstraction of DB as collection of objects". Whenever you work with collection of objects, you always get the object first before updating it. I actually wonder how ORM (like nHibernate) would work in this scenario.

Comment: @Euphoric yes I understand that's how it usually works. That's why I alluded to merging / adding an entity object into the repository.  My point is that in many implementations, the repository doesn't care if the object comes from the DB or elsewhere, only that it has an identity (ID is set).  As to keeping track of properties--  if you add the object to the repository with its identity and then set its properties, the repo should know only to update the properties whose values have changed.

Comment: The problem I have with your solution is that despite having a `Customer` instance, it is actually write-only in this context. And there is nothing indicating such. If you try to read some of it's properties, what should happen? Exception? Lazy-load? What if you have list of Customers and some of them are "materialized" while others are "proxy" like in your example? If find it hard to accept design where same class is "read-write" or "write-only" based on how it was created.

Comment: @Euphoric first of all, my example does not use a proxy object, although proxy objects are common in some frameworks.  Also some frameworks have a reload or refresh method that can be used to populate the object's properties from the persistence Store.  But it's not strictly necessary.  As I tried to explain to the OP, that extra SELECT to populate the object is necessary in a robust application anyway when dealing with stateful entities.  But it's not intrinsic to OOP.

Comment: In your example a Customer needs to be a proxy object, as it needs to track which properties change, so it can update them. Then, you are saying this : robust application, stateful entities, initial select : pick two, right? You cannot have all three? In which case, your design suggests relinquish "robust application". Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for the simplest of CRUD models, even Repository is an overkill.

The main purpose of repository pattern is to allow to query rich object model, that can then be manipulated in OOP way. This sacrifices some DB queries to gain ability to manipulate data in "better" way than plain SQL.

But in your case, it seems that there is no need for rich domain model, as you seem to be fine working with plain SQL.