# Handling composite objects in the Repository Pattern

Tags: object-oriented

I'm fiddling around with OOP in building simple CRUD systems.

I've decided to focus on using the [Repository Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) for separating Object business logic and Object data persistence (actually saving the object in a persistent data store, i.e a database).

### Saving a simple object is straightforward

```js
class Customer {

  setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

// PUT Customer
customer = new Customer();
customer.setData(data);
customerRepo.save(customer);
```

### But saving a composite object becomes a bit complicated

But what happens if my Customer class is now includes other objects that also need to be persisted in the DB?

In the following example, setting a customer's data also needs to create an
`AuditTrail` which is a set of differences between the previous data and the new data passed in `customer.setData()`.

`AuditTrail` is a class and in this example it's a classic has-a relationship between `Customer` and `AuditTrail`

```js
class Customer {
  setData(data) {
    // instantiate an auditTrailCalculator with some constants from the DB
    auditTrail = auditTrailRepo.create();
    // `calculate()` produces a diff between the previous data and the new data
    this.auditTrail = auditTrail.calculate(this.data, data);
  }

  getAuditTrail() {
    return this.auditTrail;
  }
}


// PUT customer
customer = Customer();
customer.setId(customerId);
customer.setData(data);
customerRepo.update(customer);
auditTrailRepo.insert(customer.getAuditTrail());
```

The above example looks clumsy.

- I'm instantiating the `AuditTrail` object using it's repo from within the `Customer` Object.
- For performing the whole update of a Customer I clumsily:

  - Instantiate a new Customer
  - Set it's data
  - Get it's auditTrail that was generated inside the object
  - Save the AuditTrail to the DB using the `AuditTrailRepo`
  - Save the Customer to the DB using the `CustomerRepo`

### My questions:

- Is it correct to instantiate objects from their repo's from *within* other objects?
- Should I create a factory function instead, which instantiates both Objects, `Customer` & `AuditTrail` and return a composition of the 2?
- How should I handle saving this composite object?

Comment: Is `AuditTrail` specific for Customer entity, or is it used by multiple entities?

Comment: It's specific for `Customer` entity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clear example of Aggregate as seen in Domain Driven Design.

In this case, the `AuditTrail` is part of `Customer`'s aggregate. And according to DDD, repositories are per-aggregate, not per-entity. So in your case, there would be only `CustomerRepository`, which would write an audit every time `Customer` is updated.

Comment: What if `AuditTrail` it wasn't specific to just `Customer` though? I know you requested clarification and I've stated that it is - but i'd like to know what happens in scenarios where it's not.

Comment: Also, your answer means that I can *only* create new `Customer` objects from the `CustomerRepository`, otherwise they won't include an `AuditTrail` object - which makes [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/348322/108346) obsolete right?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides When I thought about it some more, then if AuditTrail is a Value Object, then there is no problem for it to be part of multiple Aggregates, not only Customer. For the second question, yes, I always considered that creation of new entity should be done through some kind of factory, that is implemented in the persistence layer.

Comment: Thanks, one last question - In that case, `CustomerRepo.save()` would internally also call `AuditTrailRepo.save()` to save the Audit Trail right?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I would question if there even should be `AuditTrailRepo`. Or at least, it should be hidden in the persistence module.